# how to make a function to create date multiples from a timestamp series in python

Tags: python, pandas, function, date

I am  trying to make a function to automatically create date dummies from a timestamp series in python.

In example if a have a dataframe which has a date column to be able to replace that date with multiple new columns where each one is for example dayofweek or day, hour, is_year_end, business day  etc. Any part of a date i could think of.

An added thing i would like is if inside that i could also create a working week and weekend column dummy which does not seem to be an out of the box dt object.

The function i wrote look something like:

```
def get_date_dummies(df, series):
for date_part in ('is_year_end', 'dayofweek'):
    df[date_part] = df[series].dt.date_part
df.drop(series, axis=1, inplace = True)
```

the error i am getting is

`AttributeError: 'DatetimeProperties' object has no attribute 'date_part'`

which as i understand it is that i am not concatenating correctly the date_part in the df[series].dt.date_part.

Any help is greatly appreciated as i am new to python and trying to get my workflow running.

EDIT: the data come from kaggle : [ashrae energy](https://www.kaggle.com/c/ashrae-energy-prediction/data?select=train.csv) my data frame is the df_train

example for single series:
`df_train['timestamp'].dt.dayofweek`

input: Timestamp('2016-01-01 00:00:00') (like df_train['timestamp'][0] from the data)

output: 1  (like df_train['timestamp']dt.dayofweek[0]  from the data)

*Basically i am trying to create something like the part "Code #3: Break data and time into separate features" from this link [example](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-working-with-date-and-time-using-pandas/) but do it in a function so i should use a some form of loop.

Comment: can you also provide sample inputs for get_date_dummies function.

Comment: Please post the complete code with expected output

Comment: Provided some added information in the edit